# How to get exact number of columns, loop statement

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, html-table

I am making a loop that displays a table with 12 columns. It starts with the number 1912 and ends with 2013. The problem is, when it loops to 1920, it has no remainder and starts a new row. I need to get the code to make a new row after the 12th column.

This is the result I'm getting:

[image: http://imgur.com/AOIQf]

And here is what I have so far:

```
<?php
    $columns = 12;
    $Year = 1912;

    echo "<table width="755" border="1">";
    echo "<tr>";
    while ($Year <= 2013) {
        if (!($Year % $columns)) {
            echo "</tr><tr>";
        }
        echo "<td>$Year</td>";
        ++$Year;
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Your first echo statement is syntactically invalid.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$columns = 12;
$Year = 1912;
$i=1;
echo "<table width=\"755\" border=\"1\">";
echo "<tr>";
while ($Year <= 2013) 
    {
    if ($i==13)
        {
            echo "</tr><tr>";   
            $i=1;
        }
    echo "<td>$Year</td>";
    $Year++;
    $i++;
    }
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";

?>
```

Comment: Works! Thank you much. I need to get more familiarized with PHP as I am a beginner. If you know of good sources to learn and practice I will appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Just keep at it, and keep programming! On the way you will find many good resources, just like you have found StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

### SOLUTION 1

You need to append and prepend columns for the years where this matches, like so:

[image]

And here's the code for doing so:

```
<?php
    $columns = 12;
    $startingYear = 1912;
    $endingYear = 2013;

    $realStartingYear = $startingYear;
    $realEndingYear = $endingYear;

    //Find the real starting year by going back a year until we hit the right one
    while ($realStartingYear % $columns) {
        $realStartingYear--;
    }

    //Find the real ending year by going forward a year until we hit the right one
    while ($realEndingYear % $columns) {
        $realEndingYear++;
    }

    echo '<table width="755" border="1">';
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($year = $realStartingYear; $year < $realEndingYear; $year++) {
        if (!($year % $columns)) {
            echo "</tr><tr>";
        }
        echo "<td>" . ($year >= $startingYear && $year <= $endingYear ? $year : "") . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

If you want to show the other columns as well, just change

```
echo "<td>" . ($year >= $startingYear && $year <= $endingYear ? $year : "") . "</td>";
```

to

```
echo "<td>" . $year . "</td>";
```

---

### SOLUTION 2

You want to start the table with 1912, like so:

[image]

The code will be a lot simpler:

```
<?php
    $columns = 12;
    $startingYear = 1912;
    $endingYear = 2013;

    echo '<table width="755" border="1">';
    for ($i = $startingYear; $i <= $endingYear; $i += $columns) {
        echo "<tr>";
        for ($j = 0; $j < $columns; $j++) {
            echo "<td>" . ($i + $j) . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to wrap every 12 columns, just keep track of the current column and use that to determine when you should end the row (e.g. every 12th column) --

```
$col = 1;

while ($Year <= 2013 && $col++) {
        if (!($col % $columns)) {
            //...
```

Using `$Year` to determine when to wrap just complicates things.